# How do I plot the output of a system with an impulse response in matlab?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I am very new to matlab and need to plot  y1[n] = x[n] + y1[n − 1] where x[n] = [1,2,4] and an impulse response, h[n] = [1,1,1,1,1] and am not sure if I have went about it the right way

My code so far is

```
x = [1,2,4];
h = [1,1,1,1,1];
y = [];

for n=1:length(x) 
if (n==1)      

    y(n) = x(n);  
else

    y(n) = (x(n)*h(n)) + (y(n-1)*h(n));  
    end
end
stem(y);
```

Please note that I cannot use the conv() function

Comment: I believe you are using the STEP response, not impulse. Impulse would be `[1 0 0 0 0]`. However, I dont understand your question. You have a piece of code. And? Is not doing what you expect? what shoudl be doing? **WHY** are you asking a quiestion? BEcause well, you are already ploting the output! (use `plot()` instead of `stem()` , but both plot the response)

Comment: I'm just not entirely sure if it's producing the right output.

Comment: Do youknwo what output do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why it got so complicated,

```
x = [1,2,4];
h = [1,1,1,1,1];
y = [];
lh = length(h);
lx = length(x);
t = -lh - lx : lh + lx;
x(end + 1 : end + lh + 1) = 0;
h(end + 1 : end + lx + 1) = 0;
x = padarray(x,[0 max(t)],'pre');
h = padarray(h,[0 max(t)],'pre');
xinv = x(end:-1:1);
for n = 1 : length(t)
     xinv = circshift(xinv,[0 1]);
     y(n) = sum(xinv .* h);
end
y = circshift(y,[0 find(t == 0)]);
subplot(311)
stem(t,x);
xlim([-10 10])
subplot(312)
stem(t,h);
xlim([-10 10])
subplot(313)
stem(t,y);
xlim([-10 10])
```

[image]

It works fine but I believe it can be coded in a more simpler way.

Comment: Very nice Kamtal - +1.  `circshift` is important as that is what convolution requires.

Comment: @rayryeng, Thanks very much. I was expecting a more simpler code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `fft`?

```
lx = numel(x);
lh = numel(h);
m = max(lx, lh);
y = ifft(fft([h zeros(1,max(lx-lh,0)+m)]) .* fft([x zeros(1,max(lh-lx,0)+m)]));
y = y(1:lx+lh-1);
```